# how I can reference multiple Entity into one , in Code First c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ef-code-first, code-first

I have this two class

```
   public class Category 
   {
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class Filter
   {
     public int Id{ get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

And I have another Entity like this

```
public class Menu 
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MenuType MenuType { get; set; }
}
```

That the MenuType is enum Like this

```
    public enum MenuType
    {   
      Category = 0,       
      Filter = 1
    }
```

i want to know in class menu how can store Category OR Filter
i mean Menu have relate with one Category or one Filter , now how can I make this relationship?
and one other thing is maybe MenuType will extende and added some other menutype and thats class.

Comment: is this possible to write example please?

Comment: Have a base class `A` and let `Category` and `Filter` extend it. and then use `A` in `Menu` class.

Comment: Have a look at either these links [TPH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618292(v=vs.113).aspx) or [TPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618293(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to have a column Foreign Key (FK) that can reference two tables.

A option would be:

```
  public class Category
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
  }

  public class Filter
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
  }

  public class Menu
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MenuType MenuType { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? FilterId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
  }
```

Inside your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().HasOne(x => x.Category).WithMany(x => x.Menus).HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().HasOne(x => x.Filter).WithMany(x => x.Menus).HasForeignKey(x => x.FilterId);
```

And based on MenuType, you either use Category or Filter object.

Comment: Sure you can... inheritance basic of `OOP`. In Entity Framework that would be known as either `TPH` or `TPT`